# AngularJS - ng-src change events

Tags: angularjs

I have the following template:

```
<img ng-src="{% ng displayImage %}" alt="" />
<ul class="thumbnails" data-obj-id="{{ obj.id }}">
    <li class="span2" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" ng-click="selectImage($index)">
            <img ng-src="{% ng image.thumbnail %}" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`{%ng something }` transaltes into `{{ something }}`.

And directive:

```
angular.module('profileDirectives', []).
    directive('thumbnails', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            transclude: false,
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, Image, $window) {
                $scope.images = Image.query({
                    obj_id: $attrs.objId
                }, function() {
                    $scope.selectImage(0);
                });

                $scope.selectImage = function(index) {
                    $scope.displayImage = $scope.images[index].image;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

What this is doing is loading a list of images into `$scope.images` and changing `ng-src` when you click on a thumbnail. This is working correctly, however some images take some time to load and hence a loading indicator seems necessary. It seems logical to listen to the image HTTP GET request that happens because of `ng-src` change in value, and show a loading indicator while the request is loading, but I'm not sure if there is a way to listen to or capture this request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this question still standing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an HTTPInterceptor as explained on this page:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
  return function(promise) {
    // signal service to display loading indicator 
    return promise.then(function(response) {
      // signal service to remove loading indicator
    });
  }
});

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Another solution might be to display a loading indicator behind the image? I think an image turns transparent when it's not loaded yet.